# Wp7: эмулятор против реального девайса. Загрузка данных с сервера

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7

Разрабатываю приложение под `WP7`. Для тестов использовал эмулятор и все было круто. Для общения с сервером использовал `WebClient` и `RestClient`. Но протестировав уже готовое приложение на реальном устройстве обнаружилась такая вещь:

```
private void LoadData()
{
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += DownloadStringCompleted;
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(Constants.Url1));
//Point_1
}

private void DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
//Point_2     
}
```

На эмуляторе между Point_1 и Point_2 0.8-1.2 секунды.
На устройстве (HTC Radar)  между Point_1 и Point_2 15-20 секунд.

```
var request = new RestRequest(url) {Method = Method.POST}; 
//Point_3
RestClient.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
{
//Point_4
}
```

На эмуляторе между Point_3 и Point_4 0.3-0,5 секунды.
На устройстве (HTC Radar)  между Point_3 и Point_4 18-22 секунды.

У меня 3 вопроса:

- Первый: Это нормально?
- Второй: Почему это происходит?
- Третий: Как можно решить данную проблему потери времени?

Comment: Может скорость инета на девайсе тормозное?

Comment: Нет, на устрйстве и компьютере используется одна и таже сеть.

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете асинхронную загрузку. Она позволяет выполняться другим операции параллельно, следовательно, скорее всего, устройство делает еще что-то во время загрузки. Мб, обновляется...

Ну и да, насчет скорости инета на девайсе - ну и что, что одну и ту же сеть? Speedtest'ом проверяли? Или еще чем нибудь?

Comment: Проблема возникала только в режиме отладки на телефоне. решением оказалось - создание xap файла изаливка напрямую на телефон.